# Click to remove a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so I'm trying to make a full screen table which upon clicking dissapears and reveals the body itself. I found the following code on the internet and I modified it a bit already:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            /******************************************
            * Popup Box- By Jim Silver @ jimsilver47@yahoo.com
            * Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
            * This notice must stay intact for use
            ******************************************/

            var ns4=document.layers
            var ie4=document.all
            var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all

            function hidebox(){
            crossobj=ns6? document.getElementById("showimage") :
            document.all.showimage
            if (ie4||ns6)
            crossobj.style.visibility="hidden"
            else if (ns4)
            document.showimage.visibility="hide"
            }

        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <p>You can see this after a click</p>
        <div id="showimage" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0">
            <table border="0" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#000080" onClick="hidebox();return false">        
            </table>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

It works so far - the background of the table is blue and when you click it it reveals the text behind it. But what I want to do is make the background of the table an IMAGE.

I should mention I'm not a programmer and it's my first time doing this. I tried making a stylesheet with

```
    table.background { background: url("URL here" no-repeat; }
```

and changing the bgcolor to background="URL here" in different places and it just didn't work.
Please help me out, I'd really love to make this work!

Comment: loose the .background, only use table {}.

Comment: @user1721135 Post that as an answer

Comment: I don't think it matters if I add class="background" after the <table, which is what I have done

Comment: `if (ie4||ns6) {} else if (ns4) { }` wow your life sucks

Comment: Why does your title say the question is about hiding the table, when it's actually about adding a background to a table?

Comment: @PeeHaa I found the code on the internet, I don't really know what it does.. If you know an easier way to achieve the same effect that I'm going for please let me know

Comment: What about learning what you are putting up in production instead if copy patsaing something you found somewhere? Do you also put everything you found on the street in your mouth?

Comment: @Barmar My bad :/ It's still related to removing a table tho

Comment: @PeeHaa I know I should but I just don't have the time and it's not my top priority right now.. I just need to achieve this one effect this one time :)

Comment: The old browsers that that code is trying to support are not in common use these days. Just use `getElementById()` and `.style.visibility`.

Comment: @Barmar can you explain some more?

Comment: All you need is `document.getElementById("showimage").style.visibility="hidden";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select elements like so in css:

```
table {
background: url("path/file.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

everything with a dot like

```
.background {

}
```

would mean a class exists in the html like so

```
<table class="background">
```

btw your js is all messed up, use this:

```
    /******************************************
    * Popup Box- By Jim Silver @ jimsilver47@yahoo.com
    * Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
    * This notice must stay intact for use
    ******************************************/

    var ns4=document.layers;
    var ie4=document.all;
    var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all;

    function hidebox(){
    crossobj=ns6? document.getElementById("showimage") :
    document.all.showimage;
    if (ie4||ns6)
    crossobj.style.visibility="hidden";
    else if (ns4)
    document.showimage.visibility="hide";
    }
```

Comment: I tried it this way aswell but it's not working for me. If you copy my code into a .html file, change what you recommended to change and open it - does it work for you? Could be something wrong with my browser?

Comment: works for me see demo: http://jsbin.com/avihuc/1/edit

Comment: Thank you so much it works now :) I'm still a little confused as to how it wasn't working before but I'll figure it out! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your table does not have class "background", your CSS is incorrect.  You're also missing the closing parentheses in your background rule.  With your HTML, It should be more like:

```
table {
    background: url("url here") no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: sorry that was just a typo on this webpage, I wrote it correctly in my code and it still wasn't working

Comment: I copied your code into an HTML file, and used the CSS I provided above and it works for me.  Using Chrome.